# How to use SPLIT() and get Nth row in the resultset in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Suppose I split a string:

SELECT SPLIT('a,b,c', ',')

How can I get the nth element in the resulting query?

```
 SELECT SPLIT('a,b,c', ',')[2] #This doesn't work to get 'b'
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use ordinal(N) where N is an integer.

```
SELECT SPLIT('a,b,c', ',')[ordinal(3)]
```

Below would return 'c'